# How is the power dissipated equal to heat generated in an electric circuit?

Tags: power, heat

I am told that P=VI and then I'm told Heat generated is equal to VI*time. does it mean that all the power is heat energy

Comment: well, conservation of energy. Unless your circuit moves something upwards, or transmit radio waves, or light, or compresses gas, or does something else that converts energy, where else would that energy go?

Comment: Unless the energy is stored locally or transmitted out of the area, it will immediately be dissipated as heat in or near the circuit.

Comment: You drive to work (or to a friend) and then you drive home. Where has all the energy gone? You are back where you began and all you have to show for it is a receipt for petrol/diesel/gas and a warm engine. Tomorrow your engine will be cold but you'll still have the receipt.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.

If your electric circuit is a radio transmitter, then some of that power will come out as radio waves.

If your circuit is an LED and its driver, then some of that power will come out as light.